# Unable to send logs to OpenTelemetry backend (using Serilog in .Net framework 4.8)

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog, .net-4.8, open-telemetry

I am using Serilog in .Net Framework 4.8 to send logs to OpenTelemetry. I am using Elastic as OpenTelemetry backend . I am able to send traces and but not logs. Please find my below code where it writes the log to the file but not sending logs to OpenTelemetry. Can somebody help?

```
    // TRACES ----- WORKING 
    _tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
   .AddAspNetInstrumentation()
   .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
   .AddOtlpExporter(config =>
   {
       config.Endpoint = new Uri("https://abcd.es.io:443");
       config.Headers = "Authorization=ApiKey xyz";
   })
   .AddSource("SK")
   .SetResourceBuilder(
       ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
           .AddService(serviceName: "NLogger", serviceVersion: "1.0.0")
           .AddAttributes(resourceAttributes))
   .Build();

   var endpoint = "https://abcd.es.io:443/v1/logs";
   var protocol = OtlpProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
```

The traces, on the other hand, are not working:

```
   // LOGGING --- NOT WORKING
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .MinimumLevel.Error()
   .WriteTo.Console()
   .WriteTo.File(@"c:\tt\1.txt")
   .WriteTo.OpenTelemetry(
   options => {
        options.Endpoint = endpoint;
        options.Protocol = protocol;
        options.IncludedData =
                IncludedData.SpanIdField
                | IncludedData.TraceIdField
                | IncludedData.MessageTemplateTextAttribute
                | IncludedData.MessageTemplateMD5HashAttribute;
        options.ResourceAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["service.name"] = "NLogger",
            ["index"] = 10,
            ["flag"] = true,
            ["pi"] = 3.14
         };
         options.Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
            ["Authorization"] = "Basic xyz", // user:abc123
         };
         options.BatchingOptions.BatchSizeLimit = 2;
         options.BatchingOptions.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
         options.BatchingOptions.QueueLimit = 10;
     })
     .CreateLogger();
```

I tried "ApiKey" instead of "Basic" in the authorization header, but still it doesn't work. It writes the log successfully to the text file though.  Please help.

Followed this page https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-opentelemetry/blob/dev/example/Example/Program.cs as reference

Comment: ApiKey should also work too. Are you sure that the API key you're using has permission to access the log index? You could run Fiddler locally to capture the traffic and double-check the requests/responses. I'm not sure if Serilog itself can log failures to send logs.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic APM Server uses bearer authentication, so you're code should be updated to send the following header when using a secret token:

```
["Authorization"] = "Bearer xyz"
```

where xyz is your secret token retrieved from your APM server.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/7.15/open-telemetry-elastic.html#instrument-apps-apm-server

Comment: Can you elaborate on why his traces work though? He is using ApiKey authentication there as you can see, not bearer.

Comment: I misread that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the ApiKey worked. There was an access issue also for sending/viewing logs.  There is special permission required to send/view logs.